# Why am I unable to sort data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

Here is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

I am trying to sort these invoices first by type (Column B) then date, and finally by amount (which shouldn't apply, but why not).

I have checked for filters.

I have checked for blanks.

I have checked to make sure I can edit.

I have checked to make sure that the format of all cells is Text.

I've tried to just sort Column B by itself, but even that won't work.

I'm truly stumped by this!  I'll be happy to send the file to those who might be able to help.  I'm sure there must be an easy fix; I just don't know what!

Comment: When you say "won't work", do you mean it does nothing or it does it incorrectly or it gives an error? What happens if you copy and paste the data to a new sheet? Can you sort it then?

Comment: It does nothing.  The highlighted portion sometimes extends out to the the end of the sheet, but no data moves.

Well, I'll be bemused and amazed.  Copy/paste to a new sheet makes it work.

Any thoughts as to why the original wouldn't do it?

Comment: Obviously there is something wrong with the original file. There is no way I would know what is causing it. Sometimes files get corrupted during transfer, copying or emailing, etc.

Comment: It appears that your data is grouped in an Excel [outline](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-HA010095247.aspx). I suspect that this is why the data is not sorting as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if you ever got this resolved since it has been four years since you posted, but I also had the same issue. Eventually I was able to resolve my issue by selecting all the columns (at least the columns that held data, in this case columns A to F) and then sorting via the column that I needed to sort (column F from largest to smallest). Prior I was only selecting that one column that needed to be sorted (column F only) which made no changes at all.

Answer (score 1):

@Excellll had it right in the comments: Your data is grouped and you are trying to sort data both inside and outside of that group. Ungrouping everything or only sorting within the group works fine.

---

**Investigation Step 1:** I recreated your data and tried to sort it. (Aside: Your dates are stored as text so I stored mine as text, meaning there was [another dialog window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e4s3.png) after the sort window.)

[image: Step1]

The sort did nothing. No error message, no change in the data order despite *expecting* it to change because the data is not already sorted as desired.

---

**Investigation Step 2:** Try to sort just the data inside the group (rows 2-12).

[image: Step2]

This succeeded.

[image: Step2Results]

---

**Investigation Step 3:** Ungroup all the rows and try again.

[image: Step3]

This also succeeded.

[image: Step3Results]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
- Select any cell within the data table.
- Click Data >Table Tools > Convert to Range 
- Excel will ask you if you want to convert the table to a normal range.
- Click Yes.

Save your work first in case you have to undo but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this folks, may help

Select the column to be sorted > Text to column > Fixed width > Next > Next > Finish.

Then try to sort the column as usual.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

it probably wont sort because you are using one of those table formats..like automatic row shading... copy the data and paste values into a plain spreadsheet and then your sort will work, to me this is a bug., excel should allow you to sort the data and then reapply the shading rows if you want it..  thats why i never use their fancy template coloring because then later you have problems, either inserting columns or sorting which defeats the whole program.